# Scala - mutable HashMap -> write to file / read from file -> HashMap null

Tags: android, scala, serialization, hashmap, deserialization

I have this Scala code running on an Android device:

```
// create Map
val myMap1 = new HashMap[Int, String]()
myMap1.put(1, "a")

// write it to file
val outStream = context.openFileOutput("test.txt", Context.MODE_PRIVATE)
val ostream = new ObjectOutputStream(outStream)
ostream.writeObject(myMap1)
ostream.close

// read from file
val inStream = context.openFileInput("test.txt")
val istream = new ObjectInputStream(inStream)
val myMap2 = (istream.readObject).asInstanceOf[HashMap[Int, String]]
istream.close

// java.lang.NullPointerException accessing myMap2
if (myMap2.contains(1)) { println("yes") } else { println("no") }
```

I create a mutable.HashMap and write it to a file, read it and then the HashMap is null. Why is `myMap2` null and do not have any contents? Below is a screenshot of the debug session.

[image: Screenshot of Eclipse IDE - debug session]

Full stacktrace:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
  at scala.collection.mutable.HashTable$class.index(HashTable.scala:353)
  at scala.collection.mutable.HashMap.index(HashMap.scala:39)
  at scala.collection.mutable.HashTable$class.findEntry(HashTable.scala:130)
  at scala.collection.mutable.HashMap.findEntry(HashMap.scala:39)
  at scala.collection.mutable.HashMap.contains(HashMap.scala:60)
  at com.test.mytest.bean.MyItem$.read(MyItem.scala:74)
  at com.test.mytest.bean.MyItem$.add(MyItem.scala:93)
  at com.test.mytest.frag.MyFragment.onClick(MyFragment.scala:114)
  at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4084)
  at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:16966)
  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:615)
  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4745)
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786)
  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: myMap2 is not null in your example, so this is not what's causing the NPE. Can you post the whole stacktrace?

Comment: Right, but tableSize and table empty, and so it throws this error. tableSize must be 1 and table HashEntry, like ``myMap1``.

Comment: What line is MyItem.scala:74?

Comment: this one: ``if (myMap2.contains(1)) { println("yes") } else { println("no") }`` The problem is not the NPE, the problem is that the HashMap written into a file and read again is not the same. I can also do it without a ``put(1, "a")``, ``myMap1`` has tableSize ``0`` not ``null`` and table ``HashEntry`` and not ``null``

Comment: Hmm. Works for me ignoring the android stuff, so I'd guess that that's somehow the problem.

Comment: @Impredicative: What works for you?

Comment: @Tim The whole thing! Changing the `context` stuff to just using a `File` and `FileOutputStream`, your code otherwise works fine for me - the HashMap is recovered correctly and I can do the 'contains' test.

Comment: Using ``java.util.HashMap`` instead of ``mutable.HashMap`` of Scala, then reading the file, I have the content of the HashMap! So something went wrong using Scala's HashMap! (Of course, the contains() does not work with Java's HashMap, but the right values are there). So what could be the problem here? I can not serialize a mutable HashMap?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason is that `HashTable` contains a protected field `table` that is declared as "transient":

```
@transient protected var table: Array[HashEntry[A, Entry]]
```

So it is never written to the file, and when deserializing keeps its default `null` value.

However, `HashMap` defines `readObject` and `writeObject` to explictly handle the serialization (I have not taken the time to dive in the whole code but most certainly this is supposed to handle the reading/writing of the `table` field, among others) so it appears that it *should* work anyway.

Now, let me make an educated guess here: you are on Android, so most certainly you are using a tool like proguard to remove all the unneeded code (and shrink the code you do need via renamings). The problem then is that `readObject` and `writeObject` are private, so depending on your proguard configuration, proguard might assume that the methods are never accessed and thus remove them altogether. Thus at runtime, only the standard serialization is used and the custom serialization that is supposed to handle `table` never happens.

What you should do is modify your proguard configuration so as to keep the `readObject` and `writeObject` methods. The standard proguard documentation even has an example of this here (search for "readObject"): http://proguard.sourceforge.net/index.html#manual/examples.html

Comment: You saved my day! It works addding the lines to ProGuard! But I do not understand the problem, but I like to do it. I call ``writeObject`` and ``readObject`` from ``ObjectOutputStream``and ``ObjectInputStream``. What is the "standard serialization"? So HashTable overrides both methods, but there are removed by ProGuard?

Comment: And if sth. is ``transient`` it should not be serializable? But why can I then do it?

Comment: I was not talking about the `readObject`/`writeObject` methods that you are calling (the ones in `ObjectOutputStreamand`), but rather, thoses methods here: https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/v2.10.0/src/library/scala/collection/mutable/HashMap.scala#L134. In short, adding a `writeObject` in a serializable class allows to perform custom serialization logic (same thing for `readObject` and deserialization). HashMap does just that. See this documentation: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/platform/serialization/spec/output.html#861